# How to open .RAW file to see it's content except AUDACITY

Tags: audio, binary

I have converted one mp3 file to .RAW format using audacity and now i want to open it to see it's binary content.

When i opened it with notepad++... NUL.... symbols almost killed me...

If somebody knows some editor for .RAW format file shall be highly helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to provide an answer in the form of an answer, rather than commenting on the question. If you do not think there's enough value in your answer, you may want to delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to answer my own question... hex editor is the tool